# C# Efficient way to iterate over excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, iteration

I have the following code:

```
string result = "";
for(int i=2; i<=excelRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    result += excelRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2;
}
```

For an excel file with  a couple hundred entries this takes 5 seconds. Is there a more efficient way, perhaps? I only want the values from B2 to Bn.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Concatenating values from all cells?

Comment: I'm trying to get all values from the cells of the column B, except B1. My example above is only rudimentary, but that's the intention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient way.

1. Create a range that exactly matches the cells that you really need.
2. Get the *Value2* property of this range. The result will be an array type.
3. Iterate through the array

The problem with your approach is the large number of inter-process requests between your application and Excel. Your approach requires two or three requests per cell. The proposed approach is much faster because it requires a few requests up-front but not additional requests per cell.

Note that this works up to about 4000 cells. If you need to process more cells, you will need to split it into several ranges, each one containing less than 4000 cells.

**Update**

Assuming Excel is already running, it would look something like this (the correct number of rows in the B column is automatically selected):

```
var excelApp =  (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
var range = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Range[workSheet.Range["B2"],
        workSheet.Range["B2"].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown]];
var cellData = (Object[,])range.Value2;

string result = "";
foreach (var cell in cellData) {
    result += cell.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why 4000 cells?

Comment: Only Microsoft knows. It's not a hard limit. Sometimes it works up to 16,000. 4000 cells has always worked.

Comment: What do you mean *works*? Do you say, that I can't iterate over array with 100000 items?

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.

Comment: @JohnyL: If you call the *Value2* property for a range of more than 4000 cells, you can get an error. For large ranges, you need to split it into smaller ranges and call the *Value2* property for each subrange. You then have a nested loop: In the outer loop you do the inter-process request and retrieve 4000 cells at once, in the inner loop you retrieve the cell data (without inter-process communication).

Comment: This works perfectly, just implemented it and the values appear in the textbox I use immediately, no delay at all. Impressive what a difference efficient coding makes...

Answer (score 1):

The basic skeleton is the following:

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };
var xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Temp\Results.xlsx");
var xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
var arr = (object[,])xlSheet.Range["B2:B100000"].Value;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 1; x <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++x)
{
    sb.Append(arr[x, 1]);
}
var final_string = sb.ToString();

// Close workbook, close Excel...
```

Comment: This should work as well, but is a bit less elegant, I think. Thanks nonetheless.